# Regex to remove <s c r i p t> </script> tags

Tags: javascript, php, regex

Im trying to remove the `<script></script>` tags from a string in **PHP**.

I have tried to use a regex that could handle differents kinds of tags typo like `<script>` or `<sCRIpt>` or `< script>` but i dont know of to find the spaced typed words like `<s c r i p t>`.

The objective is to build a regex that is capable to remove all of the `<script>`-like tags in all typo.

here is an example of unwanted data in `$description` var :

```
<script src="https://virus.js"></s c r i pt>
```

My code, assuming `$description` is a string.

```
$description = preg_replace('/<script*\b[^<]*(?:(?!<\/script>)<[^<]*)*<\/script*>/i','',$description);
$sujet->setDescription($description);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following [**regex**](https://regex101.com/r/ld9bNO/2) can eliminate all the scripts from your string.

```
$description = preg_replace('/<s\s?c\s?r\s?i\s?p\s?t\s?>.*<\/s\s?c\s?r\s?i\s?p\s?t\s?>/gim', '', $description)
```

Comment: Thank for the usefull response, i just added a ```.*``` after the ```<script``` to remove the ```src=""``` 

So the final and usable version is the following : 
```/<s\s?c\s?r\s?i\s?p\s?t\s?.*>.*<\/s\s?c\s?r\s?i\s?p\s?t\s?>/mi```

tested on https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you’re trying to prevent script injections, a much safer way is to escape the string rather than try to replace what may be a script block. But to answer your question, you could do something like this and similar for the end tag but with the slash included for the tags.

```
<\S*s\S*c\S*r\S*i\S*p\S*t\S*>
```

Essentially this will match `<script>` with a variable number of spaces within each character.